# Ternary Conditional Operator for else if

Tags: swift

I can use the ternary conditional operator for an `if {} else {}` statement like this: `a ? x : y`, or `question ? answer1 : answer2`.

Is it possible to use this format with an `else if` clause? E.g. something like:

`a ? b ? x : y : z`

...or is this just overkill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `x` and `y` in `a ? x : y` are complete expressions, so you are allowed to put any kind of sub-expressions into them, as long as they produce results of the correct type.

However, nesting of conditional expressions quickly becomes unmanageable, so using parentheses is a very good idea:

```
let res = a ? (b ? x : y) : z
```

or

```
let res = a ? x : (b ? y : z)
```

or even

```
let res = a ? (b ? w : x) : (c ? y : z)
```

Comment: lol at the last `let res =`. I think at that point readability of `else if` trumps conciseness of the operator :)

Comment: @chicobermuda I agree - hence "or even" in place of simple "or". If you find yourself in need of writing something as complex as the last expression, you would probably be better served by a chain of `if`/`else` or in some cases, a `switch`.